# lazy fetching problem

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, lazy-evaluation

I have a problem with lazy fetching. here's what I have. I have a entity class called channel. and another entity class called show. Each channel has many show's. I've implemented hibernate with lazy fetching.But heres the problem, when I get a channel from database and after that try to access the programm list I get a nullpointerException.
Here's some code:

```
 telekanalService.findAllTelekanal(new AsyncCallback<List<Telekanal>>() {
          public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // Show the RPC error message to the user
           errorLabel.setText(caught.getMessage());

          }

      public void onSuccess(List<Telekanal> result) {
       //Programm tel = result.get(1);
       List<Programm> prog = result.get(0).getProgrammid(); //problem with this
       //Telekanal tell = tel.getTelekanal();
       errorLabel.setText("tehtud:" + prog.size()); //returns Nullpointerexception
      }
});
```

Maybe I have some mapping errors, here are my mapping files
Programm.hbm.xml:[http://pastebin.com/Q639HreT](http://pastebin.com/4c3h0fZj)
Telekanal.hbm.xml: http://pastebin.com/4c3h0fZj
Programm class:http://pastebin.com/ws57uGg2
Telekanal class:http://pastebin.com/MZB7KgT1 
Or maybe I have problem in my sql setup: http://pastebin.com/AVBM8882
And also I'm using opensessioninview for keeping the session open
[My code](http://pastebin.com/SncuycwL)
Really hope that someone can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> <list name="programmid" inverse="false" table="programm" lazy="true">
>     <key>
>         <column name="t_id" />
>     </key>
>     <list-index></list-index>
>     <one-to-many class="com.tvkava.shared.model.Programm" />
> </list>
> ```

Shouldn't declaring an empty `list-index` cause an error? I'm not sure how this would work.

Comment: Thx, I didnt know that mapping a list needs a extra column for indexes